# Bin pandas dataframe by every X rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, binning

I have a simple dataframe which I would like to bin for every 3 rows.

It looks like this:

```
    col1
0      2
1      1
2      3
3      1
4      0
```

and I would like to turn it into this:

```
    col1
0      2
1    0.5
```

I have already posted a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20134387/resample-pandas-dataframe-with-bin-size-frequency) but I have no Idea how to port the solution to my current use case.

Can you help me out?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 53, accepted):

In Python 2 use:

```py
>>> df.groupby(df.index / 3).mean()
   col1
0   2.0
1   0.5
```

Comment: such a simple and elegant solution!

Comment: I get 0.000000  2, 0.333333  1, 0.666667  3, 1.000000  1, 1.333333  0 with the latest Python and Pandas version. Probably has to do with integer division. *Edit*: Yes, Python 3 users, use `df.index // 3`

Comment: Is there an equivalent way to do this if your dataframe has a datetime index, and you were insisting on doing every `n` rows?

Comment: @Seth: You could reset the index. Not sure if you want to use every nth row. If so, use modulo (%) instead.

Answer (score 29):

The answer from Roman Pekar was not working for me. I imagine that this is because of differences between `Python2` and `Python3`. This worked for me in `Python3`:

```
>>> df.groupby(df.index // 3).mean()
   col1
0   2.0
1   0.5
```

Answer (score 4):

For Python 2 (2.2+) users, who have "true division" enabled (e.g. by using  `from __future__ import division`), you need to use the "//" operator for "floor division":

```py
df.groupby(df.index // 3).mean()
```