# Creating a line plot after every 48 rows in Dataframe

Tags: pandas, plot

So I am given thousands of lines of data of which I  inserted into a data frame using pandas. I would like to create plots that includes only 48 rows of data and after every 48 rows creating a new plot that has the next 48 rows and so on. I'm confused as to how to do that. I would also like to know how to graph only certain rows in my data frame in my line plot. P.S. this is my first question so I apologize for any formatting errors.

I isolated a certain column of my code "HP" and assigned into the variable hp by doing hp = df.HP. I also made a basic plot for the whole data already by doing hp.plot(x = '#', y = None, kind = 'line'). I've looked up my issue and tried using

```
hpnew = hp[seq(1, nrow(hp), 48), ]

hpnew.plot(x = '#', y = None, kind = 'line')
```

Where hp new would be every 48th row. It didn't work and I was left with the error message

```
NameError: name 'seq' is not defined
```

Initially I told to use

```
for i to range(hp):
  hp(i)
```

But I was left with a syntax error and was confused what to from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [answer by Roman Pekar here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20180364/2074981) to bin your dataframe into groups of 48:

```
df.groupby(df.index / 48)
```

Then if you have some plotting function you can apply it to the grouped data:

```
def plot_function(df):
    df.plot( ... )
df.groupby(df.index / 48)['hp'].apply(plot_function)
```